# request.GetResponse() gives a ProtocolViolationException when header last-modified contains "Fri, 20 Nov 2009 15:53:16 E. Australia Standard Time"

Tags: .net, http, http-headers, httpwebresponse, mongoose-web-server

Q1 - Is this a bug in .net, or is the webserver I'm using for testing ( [Mongoose](http://code.google.com/p/mongoose/) ) not server up the header field Last-Modified in the format it should?

- So in C# VS2008 if I make the call:
  `response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();`
  `Console.Out.WriteLine("  - LM = " + response.LastModified);`
- I get: ProtocolViolationException: The value of the date string in the header is invalid
- When I use HTTPLiveHeaders to look at the HTTP head for last-modified I see:

  Last-Modified: Fri, 20 Nov 2009 15:53:16 E. Australia Standard Time

Q2 - Any suggestions on how to handle so my unit tests which rely on using the Mongoose server won't have this issue?

Q3 - Anyone know if this is something that could happen on production internet web servers a lot?  i.e. should I be assuming some webservers will give the Last-Modified field back in a different sort of format that .net will balk at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1)

If you refer to the [RFC 2616 Section 14](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html), you'll see that the definition of the Last-Modified header is:

> Last-Modified  = "Last-Modified" ":" HTTP-date

HTTP-date is specified [in the same RFC, section 3](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html).

> ```
>   Sun, 06 Nov 1994 08:49:37 GMT  ; RFC 822, updated by RFC 1123
>   Sunday, 06-Nov-94 08:49:37 GMT ; RFC 850, obsoleted by RFC 1036
>   Sun Nov  6 08:49:37 1994       ; ANSI C's asctime() format
> ```
>
> The first format is preferred as an
> Internet standard and represents a
> fixed-length subset of that defined by
> RFC 1123 [8] (an update to RFC 822
> [9]). The second format is in common
> use, but is based on the obsolete RFC
> 850 [12] date format and lacks a
> four-digit year. HTTP/1.1 clients and
> servers that parse the date value MUST
> accept all three formats (for
> compatibility with HTTP/1.0), though
> they MUST only generate the RFC 1123
> format for representing HTTP-date
> values in header fields

Since the date in your header matches the first of these, with only the time zone looking different, you can check [RFC 1123](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123#page-55) to see if it's legal. Regarding time zones, this states.

> There is a strong trend towards the
> use of numeric timezone indicators,
> and implementations SHOULD use numeric
> timezones instead of timezone names.
> However, all implementations MUST
> accept either notation.  If timezone
> names are used, they MUST be exactly
> as defined in RFC-822.

From [RFC 822 Section 5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822#section-5) we can see the definition of the zone:

```
 zone        =  "UT"  / "GMT"                ; Universal Time
                                             ; North American : UT
             /  "EST" / "EDT"                ;  Eastern:  - 5/ - 4
             /  "CST" / "CDT"                ;  Central:  - 6/ - 5
             /  "MST" / "MDT"                ;  Mountain: - 7/ - 6
             /  "PST" / "PDT"                ;  Pacific:  - 8/ - 7
             /  1ALPHA                       ; Military: Z = UT;
                                             ;  A:-1; (J not used)
                                             ;  M:-12; N:+1; Y:+12
             / ( ("+" / "-") 4DIGIT )        ; Local differential
                                             ;  hours+min. (HHMM)
```

As the time zone in the header is not listed here, we can therefore conclude that it is invalid, and that the server is in fact violating the protocol, so the exception appears reasonable.

Q2)

I'm afraid I don't know how you could handle it other than putting a proxy in the way that fixes up the header to be valid, or ask the people who write/maintain the Mongoose server to fix it (or fix it yourself and submit a patch, as it's an open source project).

Q3)

I've rarely (if ever) seen a web server that .NET has had problems calling, so I don't believe this type of issue is common on the internet in general.

Comment: excellent - thanks Greg - perhaps then I should look at another light-weight web-server for testing purposes I guess

Comment: Yup.  Don't trust a webserver that blatantly ignores the HTTP specs.  You've encountered one example of this and there are bound to be others.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, anything but GMT is invalid:

"All HTTP date/time stamps MUST be represented in Greenwich Mean Time (GMT), without exception." (see [RFC 2616, Section 3.3.1, Paragraph 5](http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc2616.html#rfc.section.3.3.1.p.5))